# What is the Impala SQL equivalent function of NEXTDAY in Netezza?

Tags: date, netezza, impala

I have a `SELECT` statement that I am trying to convert from Netezza SQL to Impala SQL. The output looks something like `140612`, which is a date that is obtained by subtracting `7` from the current date and then pulling out the monday of that week.

I need to have this readable for Impala, then format it, then turn it into a string.

The query is :

```
TO_CHAR(next_day(DATE(a.date)-7, 'Monday'), 'YYMMDD') AS START_DATE
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `a.date` is a `timestamp`, and `T` is the day of the week (1 = Sunday, 7 = Saturday; for your example above, Monday = 2, so T = 2) you should be able to use use

```
date_add(a.date, 7 - pmod(dayofweek(a.date) - T, 7));
```

in place of `next_day` in the above query. Check out the [documentation on Impala's built-in date and time functions](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/latest/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html) for more detail.